# Define method of struct inside function

Tags: methods, struct, go, dependency-injection

I have this code

```
func baz() {
    type mockDatabase struct{}

    //
    //  More code
    //
}
```

I want to define a method of `mockDatabase`, so the full code would look like this:

```
func baz() {
    type mockDatabase struct{}

    func (m *mockDatabase) Foo() {
        // Implement function here
    }

    //
    //  More code
    //
}
```

The reason I want to do this is I'm injecting a dependency into a function, and I want to create a "mock object" to inject into the function (the function takes an interface as an argument and the mock object will implement the interface).

I could create the struct outside, but it seems more logical to declare the struct locally to decrease namespace clutter, especially when these mock objects will only be used once. Am I missing something here? Is it better practice to define it outside the test function so it's not long? What should I do here?

Comment: If it's actually test code then there's really no namespace cluttering happening.  pie-o-pah's answer doesn't look half bad, if you're still worried about it.

Comment: Seems like you are familiar with javascript's injection pattern. In Go, managing dependencies are more similar to Python's modules.

Answer (score 8):

Directly - no. And honestly, I think that pie-o-pah answered your question. **But.** If you still want to do it your way for some reason, you can do it with a little bit of boilerplate wrapping and clever use of closures:

```
type I interface {
    Foo()
}

type ExtendableI struct {
    foo func()
}

func (i ExtendableI) Foo() {
    i.foo()
}

func main() {
    type MyI int
    myI := MyI(42)
    foo := func() {
        fmt.Println(myI) // Close over myI making it work like a method.
    }
    ei := ExtendableI{foo: foo}
    useI(ei) // useI needs an I.
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/G2HKhjb5fk.

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic Go would be to use **package** for namespacing.

```
package mock 

type MockDatabase struct {}

func (m *mockDatabase) Foo() {}
```

In the main code, you can call from the package

```
package main

import (
        "path/to/mock"
)

var m = New(mock.MockDatabase)

func baz() {
        m.Foo()
}
```